# file hex value checking not working

Tags: javascript, file, validation, mime-types, filereader

i am checking ***mime type validation using magic number*** hex value of a file type **but its not working** its not able to check and ***returning wrong alert message*** even if the file have ***right hex value*** as header.

Below is the details in code:

---

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.fn.hasMimetype = function(ctrl) {
         try {
          ctrl.value = null;
         } catch(ex) { }
         if (ctrl.value) {
          ctrl.parentNode.replaceChild(ctrl.cloneNode(true), ctrl);
         }
        } 
    
    const fileSelector2 = document.getElementById('file')
            
        jQuery('#file').change(function(event) {
         
            
            const file = event.target.files[0]
            //alert(file.type);
            const filereader = new FileReader()
    
            filereader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            var header2 = "";
              
                var arr = (new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                header2 += arr[i].toString(16);
                     
            }   
                if(header2 !=='d0cf11e0' || header2 !=='504b34'){
                 alert(header2);
                 alert("only doc/docx files are supported");
                $('#file').hasMimetype(fileSelector2);
                }
          }
    
            filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: In my opinion, randomly make some text bold doesn't aid readability.

Comment: i have highlighted the core issue here in bold

Comment: So what hex string does it produce? What were the actual bytes?

Comment: its returning d0cf11e0 and 504b34 for doc and docx files but if i am uploading the doc or docx file its still showing error message

Comment: Actually in my opinion proper punctuation (period, comma) and capitalization (`I`, not `i`) would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always be true, regardless of the value of `header2`:

```
if(header2 !=='d0cf11e0' || header2 !=='504b34')
```

You probably want this instead:

```
if(header2 !=='d0cf11e0' && header2 !=='504b34')
```

Comment: ... simple typographical error ... Useful answer, so +1 anyway.

Comment: doc or docx can not have 2 same value its returning one only . you can run the snippet

Comment: @RickHitchcock ... only if `header2` is a string, and not some malicious object.

Comment: Yes if i upload doc or docx it will return only one value i.e.  d0cf11e0 or 504b34 if i will try for both condition, how it will work

Comment: Glad to hear it!